# why we dont have to compile the class before referencing it in another class

Tags: java

Why don't we nee to compile the other class we are referring in our class,like for eg
there is source code written as

```
public class b
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("source file");
    }

}
```

and then there is another source file

```
class a
{
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        b x=new b();


    }

}
```

and when we compile the class a,it automatically generates the class for b also...?why this is so?

Comment: It's just a `javac` implementation detail, intended to make your life simpler. Personally I prefer to always explicitly specify all the source file I want to compile.

Comment: Because that's how the compiler works? It can find things in the same compilation unit.

Comment: java compiler checks the root hierarchy

Comment: so we Don't nee to compile the class first...?

Comment: javac will automagically compile all classes (that are downlevel from their sources) that your class depends on when you compile your class.  It's both a convenience and to avoid the circularity that @meriton mentions.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to you explicitly specify the source file that is in another package? the reference file is in another package..how to referring it without compiling it ?

Comment: @user3590092: Just specify all the source files: `javac foo/Class1.java bar/Class2.java`

Answer (score 6):

Because otherwise you could not compile a program with cyclic dependencies between classes, such as

```
public class Parent {
    Child[] children;
}

public class Child {
    Parent parent;
}
```

which would be quite annoying, would it not?

Comment: It's interesting to note that this is needed because, unlike most other languages, Java does not have separate definition (.h, .def, etc) and implementation (.c, .mod, etc) files.